# Where is theTwilio node.js API reference?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

I can not find the API reference for https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node

Does it exist somewhere?

There are links, claiming to be the API docs, but are not.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/ has only a very few examples.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node seams to be a portal containing all kinds of documentation. But I can not find the API reference of the JavaScript API.

I would like to know which functions I can call on the `client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken)` object. And on the resulting objects of course.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! For Version 3.79.0 it is: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.79.0/

Comment: Glad you found that. I will point out that all the Twilio API reference documentation has examples for each of the available libraries which show how you can call the methods on the library in the context of the API documentation itself. For example, here is the [message resource with examples using the Node library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-message&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x).